# Layout quebrado nas abas do perfil

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

Conforme pode ser visto na imagem, o layout está quebrado nas abas do perfil.

Acredito que o badge informando o ganho de reputação do dia tenha empurrado a coluna de votos pra linha de baixo, causando o problema.

[image: Layout]